# How to fetch items that have not completed workflow, using powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, workflow

Using sitecore 10.0.1
Currently, I want to move items under a path, to "Approve" workflow. So how to fetch items that are not in approved state and change them to "Approved" workflow using powershell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code, in which `{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}` is orkflow state id.

```
$itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow = Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/*[@__Workflow='{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}']"
    
    foreach ($item in $itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow)
    {         
        Write-Host " -" $item.ID $item.Paths.FullPath            
    }
```

Or you can use this as well -

```
Get-ChildItem -Path master:\sitecore\content -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.__Workflow -eq "{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}"}
```

And to update you can use below -

```
$rootItem = Get-Item -Path master:"START PATH"
$language = "en"
$workflowFinalState = "WORKFLOW STATE GUID"
foreach ( $item in Get-ChildItem -Item $rootItem -Recurse -Language $language)
{
    $item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    $item.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = $workflowFinalState
    $item.Editing.EndEdit();
    Write-Host "$($item.FullPath)  --> Updated"
}
```

Or you can use this as well to update workflow -

```
$itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow = Get-ChildItem -Path master:\sitecore\content -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.__Workflow -eq "Workflow state id"}
        
        foreach ($item in $itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow)
        {         
           $item.__Workflow = "Workflow final state id"           
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@__Workflow State=` instead of `@__Workflow=`?

Comment: Let me check again

Comment: this should work

Comment: Try this - Get-ChildItem -Path master:\sitecore\content -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.__Workflow -eq "{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}"}

Comment: $item.__Workflow is changing the workflow state. I want to change the workflow value

Comment: Try above one - $item.Fields["__Workflow state"].Value = $workflowFinalState

Comment: The above solution worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach.

```
# ID of the workflow that will be set on the content items. Ex. Sample Workflow
$script:workflowID = "{A5BC37E7-ED96-4C1E-8590-A26E64DB55EA}" 

# ID of the workflow state that will be set on the content items. Ex. Approved State
$script:workflowStateID = "{FCA998C5-0CC3-4F91-94D8-0A4E6CAECE88}" 

# Create a loop recursively under a tree node like this. 
$processedItems = Get-ChildItem -Path master:/content/Home -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
   
    $_.__Workflow = $script:workflowID
    $_."__Workflow state" = $script:workflowStateID
}
```

It will change the state to Approve.